# MagicalRecord database inconsistency with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I use MagicalRecord for my project and in my database I have CDSong entity, which can be voted by multiple CDVoter entities.
[image: Database structure]

The voters are added and deleted in background using `NSManagedObjectContext.performAndWait(block:)` called from a serial dispatch queue. I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` which fetches CDSongs and displays their voters (in this simple scenario it only prints the voters' names).

Everything would be fine, but I receive crashes occassionally in NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate's controllerDidChangeContent method :-/ According to my analysis it seems like some invalid empty CDVoter (name = nil, votedSong = nil) objects appear in the CDSong.voters relationships. These empty voters are not returned from `CDVoter.mr_findAll()`.

This is the code that simulates the crash (usually after <20 button clicks the app crashes because a CDVoter's name is nil). Am I doing something wrong with contexts and saving? Putting whole test code here with database and frc initialization if somebody wants to try it out, but the problematic part is in `controllerDidChangeContent` and `buttonPressed` methods. Thanks for your help :)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import MagicalRecord

class MRCrashViewController : UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>!
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.testQueue")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initializeDatabase()
        self.initializeFrc()
    }

    func initializeDatabase() {

        MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.error)
        MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack()
        MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.warn)

        if CDSong.mr_findFirst() == nil {
            for i in 1...5 {
                let song = CDSong.mr_createEntity()!
                song.id = Int16(i)
            }
        }
        NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default().mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
    }

    func initializeFrc() {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CDSong")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
        NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>.deleteCache(withName: nil)
        self.frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        self.frc!.delegate = self
        try! self.frc!.performFetch()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        for song in controller.fetchedObjects! {
            print((song as! CDSong).voters!.reduce("", { $0 + ($1 as! CDVoter).name! }))
        }
        print("----");
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        for _ in 1...10 {
            self.dispatchQueue.async {
                let moc = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_()
                moc.performAndWait {
                    for song in CDSong.mr_findAll(in: moc)! {
                        let song = song as! CDSong
                        let voters = song.voters!
                        for voter in voters {
                            (voter as! CDVoter).mr_deleteEntity(in: moc)
                        }

                        for _ in 1...4 {
                            if arc4random()%2 == 0 {
                                let voter = CDVoter.mr_createEntity(in: moc)!
                                voter.name = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(arc4random()%26+65)))
                                voter.votedSong = song
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    moc.mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:
I tried to use MagicalRecord.save(blockAndWait:) with no success.

Comment: "The voters are added and deleted in background using a serial dispatch queue" . You should **not use your own queues** for coredata. You should use the NSManagedObjectContext PerformBlock methods **only**.

Comment: @Sneak I use the performBlockAndWait methods for working with core data, but I call them from a bg queue. I think this is ok, at least the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) don't say I can call performBlockAndWait only from main thread, they only say I should call the method from the same thread where I created the context. I must use the bg queue, because performBlockAndWait would block the graphics if called from main and calling perform only would mix the deletions and insertions (trust me, just tried it out). Thanks, I will edit the sentence

Comment: Deleted my comments that would solve your problems, typing this instead. since you are so arrogant with your "sentence editing" and "trust me", instead of questioning my points and trying to learn something. I wish you good luck.

Comment: @Sneak Oh man, sorry if it sounded like that, I don't want to argue, I questioned your points, studied the documentation around them and tested the possible solutions which would call the performBlock method only from the main queue (I used "trust me" to express that I didn't just reject the possibilities, but really tried them out). And I think that editing a misleading sentence is a normal or even desired thing in stackoverflow, isn't it? However, I'm gonna try some new ideas based on your deleted comments and let you know, if they worked...

Comment: no worries, if you want to avoid blocking your UI, you should create a NSManagedObjectContext with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType , and do your work on that instead. You can create a child context that pushes the changes to your main moc when saved. Also, don't use performBlock**AndWait**, it will of course block your UI. Here is a good tutorial on the basics, you should really look through it. https://www.raywenderlich.com/145877/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts-2 Unless there is something specific you want to achieve for some reason, avoid using your own queues with CD.

Comment: Here is the documentation (other than the tutorial) regarding how you create child context etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the reason of the crashes: Although `mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` waits until the changes are saved into rootSavingContext, it doesn't wait until they are merged into defaultContext (if they were made by a private queue context). If the rootSavingContext has been changed by another save before the main queue context merges the old changes on main thread, the merge is then corrupted (changes in NSManagedObjectContextDidSave notification don't correspond to current context state of rootSavingContext in `rootContextDidSave:` internal method of MagicalRecord).

Explanation of my proposed solution:

1. `DatabaseSavingManager` contains a private queue saving context, which will be used for all saves in the application (maybe a drawback if you want to use multiple saving contexts, but it's enough for my needs - saves happen in background and consistency is maintained). As @Sneak commented, there's no reason to use a background serial queue which creates multiple contexts and waits for them to finish (that's what I originally did), because NSManagedObjectContext has its own serial queue, so now I used one context which is created on main thread and thus must be always called from main thread (using `perform(block:)` to avoid main thread blocking).
2. After saving to persistent store the saving context waits for the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notification from defaultContext, so that it knows that the defaultContext has merged the changes. That's why no other saves than using `DatabaseSavingManager`'s saving context are allowed, because they could confuse the waiting process.

Here is the code of `DatabaseSavingManager`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DatabaseSavingManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = DatabaseSavingManager()

    fileprivate let savingDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    fileprivate var savingDispatchGroupEntered = false

    fileprivate lazy var savingContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        if !Thread.current.isMainThread {
            var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                context = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_()
            }
            return context
        }
        else {
            return NSManagedObjectContext.mr_()
        }
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(defaultContextDidUpdate(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default())
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func save(block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> ()) {
        guard Thread.current.isMainThread else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.save(block: block)
            }
            return
        }

        let moc = self.savingContext
        self.savingContext.perform {
            block(self.savingContext)
            self.saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
        }
    }

    func saveAndWait(block:  @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> ()) {
        if Thread.current.isMainThread {
            self.savingContext.performAndWait {
                block(self.savingContext)
                self.saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
            }
        }
        else {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.savingContext.perform {
                    block(self.savingContext)
                    self.saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
            group.wait()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func saveToPersistentStoreAndWait() {
        if self.savingContext.hasChanges {
            self.savingDispatchGroupEntered = true
            self.savingDispatchGroup.enter()
            self.savingContext.mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
            self.savingDispatchGroup.wait()
        }
    }

    @objc fileprivate func defaultContextDidUpdate(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.savingDispatchGroupEntered {
            self.savingDispatchGroup.leave()
            self.savingDispatchGroupEntered = false
        }
    }
}
```

And example how to use it (no `NSFetchedResultsController` crashes anymore; can be called from any thread, also very frequently):

```
    DatabaseSavingManager.shared.save { (moc) in
        for song in CDSong.mr_findAll(in: moc)! {
            let song = song as! CDSong
            let voters = song.voters!
            for voter in voters {
                (voter as! CDVoter).mr_deleteEntity(in: moc)
            }

            for _ in 1...4 {
                if arc4random()%2 == 0 {
                    let voter = CDVoter.mr_createEntity(in: moc)!
                    voter.name = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(arc4random()%26+65)))
                    voter.votedSong = song
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course, this is not the most elegant solution for sure, just the first that came to my mind, so other approaches are welcome

Comment: I am to tired to go through your answer but a tip for you I forgot to mention, turn on multithreading debugging oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging and you will know when you have threading issues.however, quick look through your answer, you should not need to wait for notifications before performing more saves. And it seems as you are still using dispatch groups and queues for saves etc. Which is still bad practice. This is not and really creats a mess for u, I think your real issue is that u are using MR with modifications instead of digging into how core data really works.

Comment: To showcase this, this is actually what you should use from iOS 10+ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1845237-automaticallymergeschangesfrompa  Without the use for messy manually tracking notification coding and merging. :)